# How to get attribute by name on TreeView

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, htmlelements

I have a html element that contains multiple childnodes. i would like to go through till the last childNode's first attribute value. I do not want to make it in a way that i define static string values(like keep giving child node names etc 4 times till the last one) to get the attribute i want. Is there a way to search on the tree in the child nodes by attribute name?

```
html element 
   childNodes: NodeList[11]
      9: div#firstsection
       childNodes: NodeList[1]
         0: div#secondsection
          childnodes: NodeList[1]
           0: div#thirdsection
            childNodes: NodeList[5]
             0: div#finalsection
```

So basically, I wanna go to the last childNodes that has 5 node list in it and choose the [0] div#finalsection and get the attribute of it.

Comment: Why can't you just access the `div#finalsection` using it's ID, which should be unique? Do you have a practical reason for avoinding CSS selector style lookup?

Comment: yes but how will i achieve this the id is in pretty low level. @TomášZato

Answer (score 0):

If the ID of the element you're looking for is unique, you can easily access it like this:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector("div#finalsection");
```

You can also search by attribute name, for example if you have

```
<div id="finalsection" data-my-attribute="test">Hello world</div>
```

then you can do

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector("div[data-my-attribute]");
```